# Netsuite logger string is too long to show up in details field

Tags: netsuite

When I log a whole Purchase or sales order record object using `JSON.stringifyy(SOobject);`,the logger don't show the whole object, What could I do to see entire object. The log level used is `Log.debug({})`

Answer (score 3):

As per NetSuite's documentation, you cannot log more than 3999 characters in one log - see excerpt from [SuiteAnswers "log.debug(options)"](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45056/kw/) page below:

[image]

For a temporary quick and easy solution to overcome this limitation in order to troubleshoot some specific part of your script, you can call `email.send()` and include the details in the email body.

Comment: Thanks very much for the workaround i didn't think about the email method. @krypton

Comment: You're welcome.  If it has helped you, consider up-voting and accepting the answer :).

Comment: Already did, also I found another way for web service request log, you can download the whole XML request send to suite talk api.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what Krypton suggested, typically I will write my long JSON or other data directly to an output text log file in the file cabinet. This I find is more reliable because sandbox will not send out emails unless specifically configured to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Our approach for long string is that we separate the long log string into several parts and print each one.

```
function logger(str) {
    str.match(/.{1,3000}/g).forEach(function(smallString, idx) {
        log.debug('part' + idx, smallString);
    });
}

var longStr = 'xxxx.....xxxxxx'; // This is your long string
logger(longStr);
```

However, I think sending mail is a better way in this case :)